# How many ways are there to arrange a m×n matrix with m×n different elements?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

Let's say we have a 4x6 matrix with 24 elements. Using letters as these elements, one way to arrange them would be:

\begin{pmatrix}
   A&B&C&D&E&F\\G&H&I&J&K&L\\M&N&O&P&Q&R\\S&T&U&V&W&X  
     \end{pmatrix}

**How many ways are there in total for this particular case? What would be a general solution for a *m×n* matrix with *m×n* elements?**

Comment: You have $24$ places to be filled with $24$ letters and assuming no repetition it can be done in $24!$ ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every location in the matrix is unique, and there are $m\times n$ possible elements to be put in one position, after which there are $m \times n -1$ possible elements to be put in the next position ... etc.

So, it is simply $(m\times n)!$